# SQL - have a result from one select into another select

Tags: sql, select, relational-algebra

I have two subqueries that I want to select two distinct columns from but I don't know how. Been trying for a long time now.

In other words, I need to do this:

```
select distinct A, B 
from (select * from selectstatement 1, selectstatement 2);
```

What I have is this.

I got two tables, table1 and table2, with three columns each of type int.

I have:

```
selectstatement 1: 
      select * 
      from table1, table2;

selectstatement 2: 
      select distinct table1.A, table1.B, table2.A, table2.B 
      from table1, table2 
      where (table1.A > table1.B and table2.A > table2.B) 
         or (table1.B > table1.A and table2.B > table2.A);
```

The problem I have now is to pick out column A and B from both of this select statements with such as `select distinct A, B from (select * from selectstatement 1, selectstatement 2);`

But all I have tried has not worked.

This doesnt work:

```
select distinct P.A, P.B, T.A, T.B 
from (    select distinct table1.A, table1.B, table2.A, table2.B 
          from table1, table2 
          where (table1.A > table1.B and table2.A > table2.B) 
             or (table1.B > table1.A and table2.B > table2.A)) as P, 
     (select * from table1, table2) as T;
```

But this is also wrong if I should do it like "`select distinct A, B from (select * from selectstatement 1, selectstatement 2);`", isnt it?

Comment: Take a look to tables alias

Comment: Query 2 looks okay. You select the four columns in question. However, which columns do you want to select in your query 1? Also P.A, P.B, T.A, T.B? You are doing a cross join there, so you get all available combinations. There cannot be any combination from query 2 that is not already in query 1. So obviously you want something different. But what? You are talking of *two* distinct columns, but you are selecting *four*. Advice: Try to explain what the result set should be like as if you knew nothing about SQL. Don't talk of joins and combined queries. Just describe the result table.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: great suggestion.  I would go further, describe not the resulting table, but just describe the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
     select t1.ks, t1.[# Tasks], coalesce(t2.[# Late], 0) as [# Late]
from 
    (SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Tasks' FROM Table GROUP BY ks) t1
left join
    (SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Late' FROM Table WHERE Age > Palt GROUP BY ks) t2
on
    t1.ks = t2.ks
```

Comment: I tried this, doesnt work, this is the same code I have above as well.

Comment: I get this problem: Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The column 'A' was specified multiple times for 'P'.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The column 'A' was specified multiple times for 'T'.

Comment: you should use Union for that

Comment: Union doesnt work because I need to do an Cartesisk produkt between two different select.

Comment: I have edited my answer so try this it will work fine.

Comment: The result I need is this one: select * from (select distinct table1.A, table1.B, table2.A, table2.B
from table1, table2
where (table1.A > table1.B and table2.A > table2.B) 
or (table1.B > table1.A and table2.B > table2.A)) as E, 
(select * from table1, table2) as I;

Comment: And from that table and need to get distinct A and B

Comment: use sql joins with group by simply fine :)

Answer (score -1):

The backtick key is in the upper left corner of most keyboards.)

Like code blocks, code spans will be displayed in a monospaced font. Markdown and HTML will not work within them. Note that, unlike code blocks, code spans require you to manually escape any HTML within!

If your code itself contains backticks, you may have to use multiple backticks as delimiters:

The name `` Tuple`2 `` is a valid .NET type name.